# CSS selector question

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
.menu a:hover {color: red;} 
.tab:hover {color:blue;}

<div class="menu">
    <a class="tab">Link</a> // will be red
</div>
```

Why should I use `a.tab:hover` to override `.menu a:hover`? Why just `.tab:hover`doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.menu a:hover` is [more specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) than `.tab:hover`, so it appears lower down the cascade order.

`a.tab:hover` is as specific as `.menu a:hover`, so the rules in those two rule-sets are applied in source order.

Answer (score 2):

The answer here comes down to what is called "specificity". To understand all about it, take a look at the section [Calculating a selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) in the CSS3 Selectors specification (there's similar stuff in the CSS2.1 spec).

Considering a base-10 system (because you don't get above a count of 10 for any level it's safe to do so), `.menu a:hover` ends up with a specificity of 021, but `.tab:hover` gets a specificity of 020, which is lower, so where a rule is defined in both, the `.menu a:hover` one will win.

If you were using `a.tab:hover`, its specificity would be 021, which is equal to `.menu a:hover`, and so it then amounts to the order in which they are specified which is applied.

Answer (score -2):

the class `.tab` must follow the object it is affecting, in this case `a`, and must be followed by the pseudoclass (or action) you want it to be activated by, in this case `:hover`

Therefore, `a.tab:hover` works while `.tab:hover` does not

Comment: Not true. From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html): 'If the universal selector is not the only component of a simple selector, the "*" may be omitted.'